# Error in importing modules when turning python script into .command?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, shebang

I have a python program that uses 2 scripts. One script is dedicated to the functions (functions.py) and the other is for the GUI (GUI.py). In functions.py, I do the following at the start:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

When I run the program (driving from GUI.py), everything works fine. When I try to turn GUI.py into GUI.command, I all of a sudden get the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Some stuff to note. I have the following shebang on both scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

I am using python3.6, Tkinter, and I am on a Mac. I also import several other modules before this one. I have also found that when using ".command", my working directory gets confused so I have done the following:

```
os.chdir('path/to/scripts/')
```

Does anybody have any idea why I would be getting this error despite it working in IDLE? Does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to update selenium. Thank you for the help 4 who looked lol